# How to add bullet points inside angular TextArea with each enter button pressed(keyup or enter)?

Tags: angular

Only Angular please!

I want to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/abhiagrawal87/m39xt/
with angular.

Angular textarea with bulleted list. which reads from array(String), then displayed all array items bulleted and user can also add more when press enter button.

I have found similar solutions like https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5zmbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
<div formArrayName="things">
    <div *ngFor="let thing of things.controls; let i=index">
        <label [for]="'input' + i">Thing {{i}}:</label>
<input type="text" [formControlName]="i" [name]="'input' + i" [id]="'input' + i" (keyup.enter)="onEnter()"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

but in this bullets are not inside textarea.

Is it possible?

I have tried :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r5zmbg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I was to achieve this http://jsfiddle.net/abhiagrawal87/m39xt/
with angular.

Comment: you need to use textarea to implement this!

Comment: wait i am help you!

Comment: You need a multiline Textarea as @Mehul Jariwala said. <textarea  style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>

Comment: I need bullets in Textarea, thats my requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it with a directive. Easy to reuse and it's "the angular way" I think..

create directive:

```
ng g directive <replaceWithName>
```

directive.ts

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDotTextBox]'
})
export class DotTextBoxDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() stringArray: string[];
  @Output() stringArrayChange = new EventEmitter();
  @HostListener("keydown.enter", ['$event']) onEnter(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.rawValue = this.rawValue += '\n• ';
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  @HostListener("change", ['$event']) change(event) {
    this.stringArrayChange.emit(this.rawValue.split("\n• "));
  }

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let temp: string = '';
    this.stringArray.forEach(item => {
      if (temp)
        temp += "\r\n";
      temp += '• ' + item;
    });

    this.rawValue = temp;
  }

  get rawValue(): string {
    return this.elementRef.nativeElement.value;
  }
  set rawValue(value: string) {
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.value = value;
  }
}
```

component HTML:

```
<textarea appDotTextBox [(stringArray)]="stringArray"></textarea>
```

component TS:

```
stringArray: string[] = ["test1", "test2", "test"];
```

don't forget to add directive to you module declarations.

I hope I could help (:

Comment: I like the directive approach, the only thing you should add is: adding a bullet on focus of textarea..

Comment: Thanks for the reusable solution @Geggi632.

Comment: I wonder if you can suggest , can we do it with ngModel as well? if yes then which is the better approach ? @geggi632

Comment: Have to try this at home.. what advantage do you expect?

Comment: This is saving data as array in db correctly and I wanna fetch it with bullets again while it is sending me data as string separated with comma like test1,test2,test3. How can I do that? Please suggest... I have tried many things...@Geggi632

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand what you mean. What result do you expect? Do you need both - string array (for db) and comma separated string?

Comment: when we add bulleted text to textarea and save it to DB as array ....in return when fetching the same value (array) to display it back as bulleted. But the returned value from DB is comma separated string so we need to format it back with next line and bullet. I am going to use ngfor to achieve it. If you have better solution please suggest.

Comment: So you are getting the saved array back from the db as "test1,test2,test3" and want to display it elsewhere with dot and new line? Or do you want to fill the directive with comma separated string?

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to focus and keyup/down events, in html template:

```
<textarea [(ngModel)]="content" placeholder="comment"
  (focus)="mytextOnFocus()"  (keyup)="addBulletText($event)"></textarea>
```

In your component:

```
content = ""; // model used for textarea
addBulletText(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
      this.content += '• '
    }

    if (this.content.substr(this.content.length - 1) == '\n') {
      this.content = this.content.substring(0, this.content.length - 1);
    }
  }

  mytextOnFocus() {
    this.content += '• ';

  }
```

This is completely based on the fiddle you shared in question. You can check the [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xctctg):

Comment: Or you can choose to use the `directive` approach as shown in other answer, that way if you need the same functionality elsewhere you can just plugin the directive and it will work!